# Getting value rather than formula in RGoogleDocs

Tags: r, google-docs

Is there an easy way to read the value of the cells rather than the formula?
By the way I only get this problem in a spreadsheet that I have published but not in spreadsheets that are private.
So for instance in a cell whose value was created by simply using the value from the cell immediately to the left in the Google spreadsheet I would prefer to get the value rather than  `=RC[-1]`

When one exports with Google Spreadsheets as a csv then that does not happen.

I am using the following line of code in R

```
y2009<-sheetAsMatrix(ts2$y2009,header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
```

Comment: Most of the spreadsheets I work with are private and a few are public. Because I am in that mixed environment I prefer to do it all in RGooglDocs.

Comment: Can't reproduce, sorry. Did you update everything to the latest versions?

Comment: @Joris Meys: unfortunately reproducing is not a problem here :) If you make a private sheet with some cells linked (equals) to others, you will get `=RC[-x]` strings instead of the real values.

Comment: I am using the latest version of RGoogleDocs for which there is a binary of the package since I work in Windows. I downloaded and used RGoogleDocs_0.4-1.zip

Comment: You might try a newer package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/index.html

Comment: @Thomas Yes, indeed. googlesheets is the correct answer now for anything to do with GoogleSheets. I have been using the package for a few months. It works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question was written 2009-09. At the time I was using RGoogleDocs to read google spreadsheets. In the last few months I discovered an actively created and maintained package called "[googlesheets: Manage Google Spreadsheets from R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/index.html)" by Jennifer Bryan and Joanna Zhao in British Columbia, Canada. At first it was only on GitHub and now it is in the Cran repository. It works well. It is good for reading and writing. It does not expose one's google password. All problems that I previously had in RGoogleDocs have been made irrelevant by googlesheets.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't stumbled upon this webpage, it looks useful (I haven't tried it myself...)

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/09/how-to-use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-data-in-r.html

It looks like the package that used to be used (RGoogleData) is currently being maintained.

Good Luck!

Comment: Actually, the solution on that page isn't reliant on any R package. It works well, as long as you have no issues with making your Google Spreadsheet publicly accessible.

Comment: Yeah, I should have separated my ideas there.  I was just saying that if the information on that page didn't work, there is also the RGoogleData package which is currently out of commission.

Comment: maybe you want to check out this, too: http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2012/03/r-function-to-read-data-from-google.html#more

Answer (score 1):

Not a clever solution, but evaluating the formula does work. For example with the following function:

```
getValues <- function(x) {
    m <- apply(x, 2, function(x) as.character(x))
    for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
        formulas <- which(substr(m[i,], 1, 4) == "=RC[")
        t <- sub('=RC[', '', m[i, formulas], fixed=TRUE)
        t <- sub(']', '', t, fixed=TRUE)
        t <- as.numeric(t)
        m[i, formulas] <- m[i, (formulas + t)]
    }
    return(m)
}
```

`getValues(y2009)` should return a data frame with all required values. I know this is a quite dumb "solution" with lot of compromises but I hope you could code a lot cleaner function for the task! :)

Comment: And of course a smart `regexpr` would simplify the function, but unfortunately I have no deep experience with regular expressions :(

Comment: Thanks for trying but it does not work. In my latest iteration of the problem, the formula in the column is =RC[-2]&"_"&RC[-1]. It is very simple. It takes the contents of the cell two to the left and pastes it to the contents of one to the left and puts an underscore between the two character values. I was able to easily replicate it in R but it still does not solve my basic issue of RGoogleDocs is importing the formula rather than the value of the formula. The spreadsheet I tried today is published so that anyone with the link can view it but I was still signing in through the getGoogleAuth

Comment: @Farrel: I see. I thought that you have all those simple "functions". A bit deeper level of coding might "solve" your problem, though I have no idea what could be the cause of this strange occurrence. I will check back later to see if you could solve the question!